# This is not an 18650 battery. Is it something else or completely non-standard?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I bought a device from China that was supposed to come with 18650 rechargeable cells but these are both wider and taller than normal 18650 cells.

They are about 18.25mm in diameter and 69mm tall. They will not fit into a battery compartment due to their larger size and cannot be forced to do so.

Are these a standard size or are they one-offs that will only fit into devices specifically made for them?

[image]

[image]

Here it is next to a genuine 18650 for comparison.

[image]

Comment: The brand name does not inspire confidence.

Comment: Li-ion cells with numbers like this are supposed to be dimensional, e.g. 18 mm diameter, 65.0 mm length. My guess is UltraFire didn't get the memo.

Comment: Is it 18650 + protection?

Comment: They are probably over-length due to a protection circuit. The overage in diameter may be within specification. 0.25 mm is only slightly over-size. One would not expect it to be 18.00 mm exactly.

Comment: "Ultrafire" is a generic name: you can buy the sleeves on AliBaba and slide them on any cells.

Comment: @DavideAndrea *Oh, great*.  Thank goodness the UL and RU marks still mean something.

Answer (score 1):

Cells like these infuriatingly don't follow any standard. Yes the 18650 means the cell has a diameter of 18mm and a length of 65.0mm but then a lot of manufacturers started adding in proprietary protection features. Things like temperature sensors, over current and over voltage discharge protection circuitry is often added near the end caps and then re-wrapped to look like just a cell. The wrapper itself does not follow any standard either and many of my batteries have scraped off labeling from the compartment being too tight.

If the battery doesn't fit length wise there is not much I'd do except buy a better quality cell since you don't want to remove protection hardware the manufacturer decided they needed. If it doesn't fit diameter wise you can try removing the wrapper and seeing if that helps. Personally I would google for reputable cells. Think samsung, panasonic, sony, etc. 99% of off brands from china have all their ratings inflated.

Comment: FWIW it *is* a protected one : https://www.batteryjunction.com/ultrafire-brc-18650.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwhaaKBhBcEiwA8acsHGmvPhwTwVyJ5ebUAF4LAAxMB3JzjPmpDlsXt-ohEUAXmpgJugxnbBoCRtoQAvD_BwE There are many google result about these BTW, so looks like it is not just some no-name brand

Comment: Ultrafire is a well known brand of poor quality battery. Some of the ones tested on Google show 5-10x lower capacity than claimed.

Answer (score 1):

This battery *really is* a standard 18650, except it has an onboard BMS to protect the cell.  The typical BMS is a button shape, 18mm diameter and about 4mm tall.  That's standard too.

You can see the lump in the battery shrinkwrap, plain as day.

These things are not as common as raw unprotected 18650s, but are readily available if you know to ask for that.

They are a smart choice for a device designer to use, if their device will support charging, because it offloads charge protection onto the battery itself.

The purpose of the BMS (Battery Monitoring System) is to protect the cell from overcharge voltage, excessive current in/out, over-discharge and thermal problems.   On lithiums, you really need that.  You may be accustomed to devices which provide it in the device and use unprotected batteries.